# Plus/minus Year and quarter from the previous quarter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What SQL code can I use to add certain years from the previous quarter? I also need to plus/minus quarters from previous quarter.

I know how to get the previous year:

```
datepart(year, getdate()) - 1 as 'Year'
```

But in January, we run run reports for Q4 2018, and if I run this part of code in Jan 2019, it will return 2018.

That is why I wanted to see if I can get the year of the previous quarter

Comment: `But in January, we run run reports for Q4 2018, and if I run this part of code in Jan 2019, it will return 2018.` What's wrong with that ? what do you want ?

Answer (score 1):

```
datepart(year, dateadd(year, -1, getdate())) as 'Year'
```

Answer (score 0):

I take your meaning to be that, whatever quarter you are in, you need to report on the previous quarter.  So if today is Jan-Mar 2019, you need to report on 4th quarter of 2018.  If it's Apr-Jun 2019, the report will be 1st quarter of 2019, and so on.

Subtract 3 months to give you a date in the previous quarter. The year part of that date will give you the year you are looking for. Take the month part of that date, add 2 and divide by 3 to get the quarter.

```
create table TestData(Today date)

insert into TestData ( Today ) values
( '2019-01-12' ),
( '2019-02-15' ),
( '2019-03-20' ),
( '2019-04-10' ),
( '2019-05-23' ),
( '2019-06-30' ),
( '2019-07-01' ),
( '2019-08-10' ),
( '2019-09-03' ),
( '2019-10-31' ),
( '2019-11-16' ),
( '2019-12-31' ),
( '2020-03-03' )

select 
  Today,
  datepart(year,dateadd(month,-3,Today)) as [Year To Report],
  (datepart(month,dateadd(month,-3,Today))+2)/3 as [Quarter To Report]
from TestData
```

Results:

```
Today      Year To Report Quarter To Report
---------- -------------- -----------------
2019-01-12 2018           4
2019-02-15 2018           4
2019-03-20 2018           4
2019-04-10 2019           1
2019-05-23 2019           1
2019-06-30 2019           1
2019-07-01 2019           2
2019-08-10 2019           2
2019-09-03 2019           2
2019-10-31 2019           3
2019-11-16 2019           3
2019-12-31 2019           3
2020-03-03 2019           4
```

Answer (score -1):

--run date: '2019-04-10'
--Output:    2019

```
select case when Month('2019-04-10') = 1 Then Year('2019-04-10') - 1 else Year('2019-04-10') end
```

--Run date: '2019-01-10'
-- output:   2018

```
select case when Month('2019-01-10') = 1 Then Year('2019-01-10') - 1 else Year('2019-01-10') end
```